# Prevent Font Size reflection in appllication

Tags: android, fonts, textview, settings

While testing for an application I found an unknown behavior. I have defined some certain font size for TextView I am using. Now if I go in Device Setting -> and Change Display-?>Font size then it reflect in application as well. Font get tiny/large as what set in settings.

Any suggestion how can prevent from this.

Comment: I like your question.

Answer (score 1):

You might be using sp while defining font size in xml. To prevent this behavior you can use dp instead of sp.

> An sp is the same base unit, but is scaled by the user's preferred
>   text size (it’s a scale-independent pixel), so you should use this
>   measurement unit when defining text size (but never for layout sizes).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I don't think your solution make sense.

Comment: Please try it once for some text views, and let me know.

Comment: @AshishTamrakar I checked it and it's working but it contradict standard to use sp for fontSize instead dp..M D please provide your suggestion as well.    http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:textSize

Comment: @Shubh - It is recommended to use sp, so that use can change the font size as per their visibility. But i thought it is your requirement and so i provided this solution, which i am also using for specific purposes.